# Is it permissible to shape the beard with a razor?

Tags: halacha, beard

I know it's prohibited to use razor to cut the beard, but is it also prohibited to shape the limits of the beard with it? If not, how can one define/line up/shape the beard?

EDIT: When I say shape the beard, I mean to cut hair at the edges of the face, that is,  [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DsjgP_Bq254/maxresdefault.jpg) or [this](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2350/4849/products/product-image-288045728_1024x.jpg?v=1511069107).

Comment: Hi Jonhz. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "shaping" and "limits of the beard". Perhaps include a drawing? Does shaping refer to cutting hair at the edges of the face? Do you mean like curling the hair? Please edit to clarify so people can be sure to help you get exactly what you're looking for

Comment: I have just edited!

Comment: Hmm this might be a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16119/759

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch ([Yoreh De'ah 181:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.181.11?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he)) strongly suggests **not** to do so, since nobody really knows the Biblical boundaries fo the beard; if you *guess* wrongly, then you've transgressed a Biblical prohibition by crossing that boundary.

> פאות הזקן הם ה' ורבו בהם הדעות לפיכך **ירא שמים יצא את כולם ולא יעביר תער על כל זקנו** כלל (ואפילו תחת הגרון) (ב"י בשם אגרת ר"י וסמ"ג):‏

The commentators remark that even passing a razor over one's mustache or around the throat-area is not recommended.